# how to "toString()" GWT EntityProxy derivatives for logging and debugging?

Tags: java, gwt, logging, apache-commons, tostring

GWT 2.1.1 has very good framework - RequestFactory with all the EntityProxy and stuff.

I am looking for a way to serialize runtime instances that implement EntityProxy for debugging and logging etc. I do not care for format as long as it human readable. 
To be more specific I would like to have something like the provided by Apache Commons Lang
[ReflectionToStringBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html)
May be there is some way to use the JSON serialization mechanics that GWT has inside? if yes how to make it a bit more readable?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder;

String stringRep = ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least 2 solutions:

First: Based on the idea by [Thomas Broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116472/thomas-broyer)

```
public static String toString(EntityProxy entityProxy)
{
    DefaultProxyStore store = new DefaultProxyStore();
    Swap.requestFactory.getSerializer(store).serialize(entityProxy);
    return store.encode();
}
```

Which produce something like this:

```
{"V":"211","P":{"1@2@biz.daich.swap.shared.dto.UserAccountProxy":{"O":"PERSIST","R":"2","Y":1,"T":"biz.daich.swap.shared.dto.UserAccountProxy","P":{"id":null,"items":null,"channelId":null,"lastActive":1296194777916,"name":null,"emailAddress":"test@example.com","lastReported":1296194777916,"lastLoginOn":1296194777916}}}}
```

Second: Based on the [AutoBean framework](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean)

```
public static String toJson(EntityProxy entityProxy)
{
    return AutoBeanCodex.encode(AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(entityProxy)).getPayload();
}
```

Which produce string like

```
{"emailAddress":"test@example.com","lastActive":1296194777916,"lastLoginOn":1296194777916,"lastReported":1296194777916}
```

The second is just what I need - it more readable in log.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it but have a look at [RequestFactory#getSerializer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/RequestFactory.html#getSerializer%28com.google.gwt.requestfactory.shared.ProxyStore%29), there's some sample code in the javadoc for the [ProxySerializer](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/requestfactory/shared/ProxySerializer.html).

Comment: Thanks I found 2 answers to the question following your idea!

Answer (score 0):

If using the method
toJson(EntityProxy entityProxy)

change this to

toJson(BaseProxy proxy)

and then you can log Value and Entity Proxy objects.